# Reading custom objects from additional YAML in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a task of reading settings from a YAML file in a Spring Boot application. The requirement is that these settings are stored in a specific file, separate from application.yml. The file is called applicationFeatureToggles.yml and is supposed to have contents like these:

```
features:
  - key: feature1
    isEnabled: false
    description: First feature
  - key: feature2
    isEnabled: true
    description: Second feature
...
```

What I need to implement right now is to check in my components' code if a specific feature is enabled. To do this, I created a class for a single feature:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Feature {
    private String key;
    private boolean isEnabled;
    private String description;
}
```

then a configuration properties class to store all settings:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:applicationFeatureToggles.yml", factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory.class)
public class FeatureProperties {
    private List<Feature> features;
    
    // Constructor, getters and setters
}
```

and a service that uses it to check if a feature is enabled:

```
@Service
@EnableConfigurationProperties(FeatureProperties.class)
public class FeatureService {

    @Autowired
    private FeatureProperties featureProperties;

    // logic that reads required info from featureProperties
}
```

The class YamlPropertySourceFactory used in FeatureProperties looks like this:

```
public class YamlPropertySourceFactory implements PropertySourceFactory {

    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> createPropertySource(String name, EncodedResource resource) {
        YamlPropertiesFactoryBean factory = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
        factory.setResources(resource.getResource());

        Properties properties = factory.getObject();

        return new PropertiesPropertySource(resource.getResource().getFilename(), properties);
    }
}
```

As I understand, this should result in FeatureService having access to FeatureProperties populated with data from applicationFeatureToggles.yml, but the data is missing. At the same time, I checked with a breakpoint that YamlPropertySourceFactory is invoked and reads the data, it's present in the properties object before exiting createPropertySource(). So all seems fine with reading properties from the file, but they don't get into the FeatureProperties object.

What else can my code need to populate FeatureProperties?

If it's not possible at all or can cause some other issues, I'd also be thankful for details, as it may help convince the architect to change the approach.

Spring Boot version used: 2.5.6

Comment: A side question, what is the point of having feature toggles in an properties like file (yaml) if you can't actually toggle them? If you have only one instance of you app running it is fine to have the file and control in memory as long as you are willing to do so every time your app restarts, now if you have two instances of the same app it will be even more problematic to control the toggles... This doesn't answer your question of course but it might save you some future troubles if this is the path you are choosing.

Comment: I don't know the details yet, but it's going to be some centralized solution for multiple apps that will depend on this yaml being named the same in all apps and having the same structure.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the cause. One other thing I did in my code was calling FeatureService in an SpEL expression in a @Conditional for another bean. So it seems FeatureService tried to initialize before FeatureProperties. Without this condition, FeatureService gets proper FeatureProperties.

I think I will eventually find a workaround now, but would be thankful if someone knows how to conditionally initialize a bean depending on some ConfigurationProperties if it also involves some logic to process the configs.